# Error while creating new Azure app service plan for a webapp

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a new Azure webapp created and I want to move it a separate web app service plan to apply custom domain (Not available on free tier). From the new Portal I try to create new Web App Service plan and get this error.

> Failed to create App Service plan.
>
> Failed to create App Service plan . There was an error processing your request. Please try again in a few moments."

Even while creation of the web app if I select create new App Service Plan it automatically goes into Free Plan.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with my web apps, could this be a general problem of the azure platform?

Comment: I got answer from the azure team that they are aware about the bug and working on it. Meanwhile use  the current portal to manage the web apps. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/45156bef-d8ce-4725-8626-cc510b831851/error-while-creating-new-app-service-plan-for-a-webapp?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received confirmation from Azure team that this issue is fixed and working on the new portal.

Check the thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/45156bef-d8ce-4725-8626-cc510b831851/error-while-creating-new-app-service-plan-for-a-webapp?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview